# 'Multiplied' but for feelings

Tags: single-word-requests

For example:

> As victims read and reread cyberbullying messages, their feelings are ____.

What verb can be used for emotions, instead of ***multiplied***?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use ***[amplified](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amplified)***:

> a :  to make larger or greater (as in amount, importance, or intensity) :  increase
>   b :  to increase the strength or amount of; especially : to make louder
>   <sub>*from [m-w.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amplified)*</sub>

Answer (score 6):

You could also try **intensified**:

> - To increase in degree or strength, or to make something do this

from Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English (by account access)

Comment: Can you edit your post to include a definition that can be accessed by a public link? Answers without traceable support carry less weight.

Comment: Yes, not amplified. Sounds are amplified. Feelings are intensified.

Comment: @Lambie What proof do you have that feelings can't be amplified?

Comment: @Hank Not everything requires proof. But my ear tells me that. In any event, it is not "the" feelings, just feelings. In any event, it's slightly ambiguous.

Comment: @Lambie I'm not saying it does, I just don't see any reason, aside from your ear, as to why amplified does not apply to feelings.

Answer (score 2):

[***heightened***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/heighten?s=t)

> heighten: to strengthen, deepen, or intensify *to heighten the plot of a story; to heighten one's awareness or appreciation; to heighten one's suffering.*

This word is especially effective in the example sentence, because it is used in connection with both heightened emotions but also heightened senses.  So your reader or listener will make connections with the physiological reactions to the bullying.

Comment: This implies a one-dimensional vertical numeric scale. That may not be the way you want to characterize emotions.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for ***aggravated***. To *aggravate* means

> to make worse, more serious, or more severe : to intensify unpleasantly ([M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aggravate))

> - The stigmatizing psychological pressure of performance during the timespan when universities were shut led to ***aggravated*** feeling of guilt, shame, regret ([source](https://www.intechopen.com/online-first/80690))
> - Their sudden separation from their families coupled with their being immersed in a new family in foreign territories ***aggravated*** their feeling of homesickness. ([source](https://knepublishing.com/index.php/KnE-Social/article/view/2422/5322))

Answer (score 1):

We're speaking about *feelings*, so words such as *heightened* and *amplified* are not necessarily associated with pejorative states. One can have *heightened feelings of* love, joy and ecstasy, likewise one can also experience *amplified emotions of* relief, hope and joy.

In the OP's example sentence I'd suggest *pummel*, it's rarely used in a positive setting.

> As victims read and reread cyberbullying messages, their feelings are **pummelled** [until exhausted].

[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pummel) defines **pummel** as:

> to strike repeatedly with or as if with the fists
> *This was a true test for a team whose confidence was being pummelled.*
> <sub>The Guardian (2021)</sub>

Comment: I can see confidence being pummeled, but not feelings.